# ravendb database with ntfs compression

Tags: compression, ravendb, ntfs

I'm trying to use NTFS compression to compress a RavenDb Database.
It's working to change folder attributes to Compressed, but when I start ravendb server, database no longer cannot be access it . I'm receiving : 
"Failed to create database testdb One or more errors occurred."
"Could open database named: testdb One or more errors occurred."

Any clues?
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318116):

> Do not put files that are managed by extensible storage engine (ESENT or ESE) on a compressed drive. Placing a Microsoft Jet database on a compressed drive may cause write-through delays that can cause Jet database corruption.

RavenDB uses ESENT (Jet Blue) as its document store.  So the answer is - **DON'T DO THIS**.

If you want compression, use the [RavenDB Compression Bundle](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/server/extending/bundles/compression).